# Finding the length of a line in a circle when given the lengths of the sides of a triangle inside the circle

Tags: geometry, circles

First and foremost, sorry if this was a terribly worded question. I'm pretty new to this and haven't quite got the hang of asking specific questions.

In the diagram below, I'd like to find out the length of $AX$ when $AB=6, AC=5,$ and $BC=9$.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6H5P.png)

At first, I tried to draw a new triangle $AYX$ to solve the problem, but it didn't really help at all.I can't think of any other way of solving the problem, so I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

PS: Sorry for the super-low quality image. I drew it in MS Paint. If anyone here knows a better way to draw math diagrams, I'd love to know.

Comment: Are $A$ ,$B$ and $C$ centers here?

Comment: Assuming the answer to haqnatural is "yes," from the diagram, it looks like (1) the large circle is tangent to the two small circles, and (2) the large circle and small circle intersect at points $X$ and $Y$. In general, it is not possible to satisfy both conditions simultaneously. Could you please clarify which is the case for your problem?

Comment: If $r_C,r_B$ are the radii of the circles with centers $C,B$ respectively , and $r=\overline {AX}$ is the radius of the large circle then $5=r-r_C,6=r-r_B,9=r_C+r_B$.

Answer (score 1):

Trusting that $A,B,C$ are the centers of the apparent circles and that all apparent points of tangency are in fact points of tangency we define  $r_C,r_B$ to be the radii of the circles with centers $C,B$ respectively , and $r=\overline {AX}$ to be the radius of the large circle. We see at once that $$5=r-r_C\quad \quad 6=r-r_B\quad \quad 9=r_C+r_B$$

Adding the first two equations yields $$11=2r-(r_C+r_B)=2r-9\implies \boxed {r=10}$$

Comment: With r=10 we have r C = 5 which implies the point A is on the circle C. The  diagram shows differently.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani  Good point.  But the algebra shows that either $A$ is on the $C-$circle or the given data in inconsistent.  Up to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

We have a system of the equations:

\begin{eqnarray}
r_A-r_B &=& 6\\
r_A-r_C &=& 5\\
r_B+r_C &=& 9
\end{eqnarray}

We are interested in $r_A$. If we sum all equations we get $2r_A = 20$, so $r_A =10$.

Comment: Your solution indicates that point A is on circle C which is not the case in the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram is not consistent with the data provided. With the given data we get the radius of circle C to be 5 which locates the point A on the circle C.

Comment: I'm very sorry if the diagram was drawn poorly. I did it in MS Paint, so as you might expect, it wasn't a very accurate depiction. Do you know of any better way to draw diagrams like these so that I can make them more accurate?